# Induction Problem from Putnam and Beyond

Tags: induction, contest-math

I have copied the first step of the solution below in order to save time and space, the problem, with full solution, can be found in the book *Putnam and Beyond*.

Question:
Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, \ldots$ be a sequence of distinct positive integers. Prove that for any positive integer $n$,

$$a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_n^2 \ge \tfrac{2n + 1}{3}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n).$$

Solution:
$$a_{n+1}^2 \ge \tfrac{2n + 3}{3}a_{n+1} + \tfrac{2}{3}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n) \ldots$$

Note:
 I understand how to make the jump from the question to the inductive step, namely replacing $n$ with $n+1$, but I don't see where the term $\tfrac{2}{3}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)$ came from in the solution.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something seems wrong here.  If we take $n=1$ and set $a_1=2,a_2=1$ then your desired inequality (in the proposed solution) appears to read $1≥\frac 53\times 1 +\frac 23\times 2=3$, or am I misreading something?

Comment: At a guess, you left off crucial information.  Possibly, say, the writers remarked that you can assume that the sequence is strictly increasing (since the desired theorem just works with the sum over the first $n$ indices it is immune to permutations of the first $n$). But I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  As I say, I expect you left off crucial information.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: The question certainly omits details (such as the rest of the proof) but it is quite clear anyway, because the details of the proof are irrelevant to resolving this confusion.

Comment: @lulu $n$ is the length of the sequence, not an arbitrary value.

Comment: There is nothing missing from this question, it is provable as stated.

Comment: @DanielV  Not following.  I am not talking about the original statement , but rather the statement in the proposed solution (which is what the OP is asking about). That statement is true if you assume that the sequence is strictly increasing, but that assumption does not appear anywhere.  The statement is false as written as is shown by the counterexample I provided.  Indeed, taking $n=1$ the statement reads $a_{2}^2≥\frac 53\times a_2+\frac 23\times a_1$ which is clearly false for sufficiently large $a_1$.

Comment: @lulu Right, you do have to assume that $a_{n+1}$ is the largest value to prove the stated formula, but just to show how the formula is derived you don't need that assumption.

Comment: @DanielV  Still not following.  The statement follows trivially from the induction statement, by simple subtraction.   I assumed that the question concerned the apparent falseness of that statement.  Perhaps the OP could weigh in.

Comment: @lulu Huh, I don't find it trivial...are you sure you are taking into account that $\frac{2n+1}{3}$ becomes $\frac{2n+3}{3}$ before doing the subtraction?

Comment: @DanielIV  Inductively $a_1^2+\cdots a_n^2≥\frac {2n+1}3\times (a_1+\cdots a_n)$.  If we could show that $a_{n+1}^2≥\frac {2n+3}{3}a_{n+1}+\frac 23\times (a_1+\cdots +a_n)$ then we can simply add the two to obtain the desired claim for $n+1$.  The only difficulty I see is that the second inequality is false, without extra information.

Comment: @DanielV  Not to belabor the point (too late! I expect), if you have two sequences $A_n,B_n$ and you wish to show that $A_n≥B_n$, the most natural sort of induction would lead you to check it for $n=1$ and then show that the differences satisfied $A_{n+1}-A_n≥B_{n+1}-B_n$.  That reasoning instantly leads to the proposed statement.

Comment: @lulu Oh *that's* the statement you meant was trivial.  I misunderstood, yeah it is I guess.  I tend to do transitivity rather than subtraction though because I don't trust myself not to make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The $\frac23(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n)$ term appears because the coefficient of those terms increases from $\frac{2n+1}{3}$ to $\frac{2(n+1)+1}{3} = \frac{2n+1}{3} + \frac23$.

For example, to go from $n=2$ to $n=3$ in the inductive step, we assume that the inequality $$a_1^2 + a_2^2 \ge \frac53(a_1 + a_2)$$ holds, and want to prove the inequality $$a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 \ge \frac73(a_1 + a_2 + a_3).$$ Take the difference and you see that it's enough to prove that $$a_3^2 \ge \frac23 (a_1 + a_2) + \frac73 a_3.$$

Answer (score 0):

An inductive approach would use $$a_1{}^2 + \dots + a_n{}^2 \ge \frac{2n + 1}3\bigg(a_1 + \dots + a_n\bigg)$$ to establish $$a_1{}^2 + \dots + a_n{}^2 + a_{n+1}{}^2\ge \frac{2(n+1) + 1}3\bigg(a_1 + \dots + a_n + a_{n+1}\bigg)$$

by using transitivity of $x \ge y \text{ and } y \ge z \text{ implies } x \ge z$.  So $x,y,z$ must be figured out.  We can choose $x$ and $y$ as:

$$x = a_1{}^2 + \dots + a_n{}^2$$
$$y = \frac{2n+1}{3}\bigg(a_1 + \dots a_n\bigg)$$

but then to figure out what $z$ has to be, we have to choose $z$ to make the last equation $x \ge z$ :

$$z = \frac{2(n+1) + 1}3\bigg(a_1 + \dots + a_n + a_{n+1}\bigg) - a_{n+1}{}^2$$

So we are given $x \ge z$ by inductive hypothesis, we know the goal is $x \ge z$, we need to establish now $y \ge z$:

$$\frac{2n+1}{3}\bigg(a_1 + \dots a_n\bigg) \ge \frac{2(n+1) + 1}3\bigg(a_1 + \dots + a_n + a_{n+1}\bigg) - a_{n+1}{}^2$$

which is

$$a_{n+1}{}^2 \ge \bigg(\frac{2n + 1}3 + \frac{2}{3}\bigg)\bigg(a_1 + \dots + a_n + a_{n+1}\bigg) - \frac{2n+1}{3}\bigg(a_1 + \dots a_n\bigg)$$

which is

$$a_{n+1}{}^2 \ge \frac{2n + 1}3 a_{n+1} + \frac{2}{3}\bigg(a_1 + \dots + a_n + a_{n+1}\bigg) $$

Comment: An easy way to finish the proof btw is to assume $a_{n+1}$ is the largest value of the sequence, so set $a_{n+1} = (n + 1 + \epsilon)$ and $$a_1 + \dots + a_{n+1} \le (a_{n+1} - 0) + (a_{n + 1} - 1) + \dots + (a_{n + 1} - n) = (n + 1)a_{n+1} - n(n+1)/2 = (n+1)(n + 1 + \epsilon) - n(n+1)/2$$  Just plug in to get an inequality without $a$ but only containing $n$ and $\epsilon$ and the result is pure algebra.